# Windows bluetooth event notifications event from cheap smart watch

Tags: microsoft-windows, smart-watches

My son got a 20 dollar Hype smartwatch and paired it with our computer, he could use it to play Windows media player even though there was nothing in the manual that said I could pair it with Windows.

How do I do what Windows media player is doing in my own applications?  (not sure where I'd be starting - I think I'd be programming in C++, C# or Delphi). I found this [supporting Bluetooth Event Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536852(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN article.  I'm guessing it's the right place to start.

There's no manual or spec that comes with the watch, whenever I search for anything related, I wind up at a Chinese website.  But, it's my assumption, that Bluetooth can interface with something that I program in a way totally ignorant of the device, only knowing I'm pushing "next, prev, play, pause, or moving the jog dial".

So, what is that API called, and how do I get get the appropriate hooks in a Windows application?

Comment: Can you give us examples on "what Windows Media Player is doing in my own applications"?

Comment: I haven't done this for a while and am fuzzy on the details, but my recollection of Bluetooth media keys in C#/WPF is that they're just passed by the OS as keypresses - MediaPlayPause, MediaStop, MediaPreviousTrack, MediaNextTrack, etc.

Comment: This is a potentially useful question, but at the minute it's hard to answer without a few more details. Is the watch just sending a command to your computer to play, or is it playing from the watch itself? Did you have to install anything on your computer? Also, if you have any link to a manual/specification for the watch, that would be brilliant - I can't find much at all about the device from what you've said, apart from the Amazon page for it.